# Processing a single message using Spring jms

Tags: spring, jms

I am working on an existing Spring jms application that pulls messages from ActiveMQ using jms:inbound-gateway. This application is a job processor that takes jobs off a queue and sends results back to the queue. Everything currently works great.

I would like to modify this application to accept one and only one job, process it, and then exit, but I have not been able to find a way to cleanly do this. The method that is called must return the results, and the results are automatically placed back onto the queue by Spring. Is there any way to tell Spring to stop accepting messages at 1? How would you know when it's done sending the reply message so you can exit.

In a more general case, if you had an application that wanted to stop accepting messages and finish processing them all so you could exit cleanly, how can that be done?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be using JmsTemplate.receive .  Inbound gateway is meant for a message driven model.  It sounds like while you are using a message queue for transport, you're not really doing a message driven model of processing.  Obviously that's not a problem but if your aim is to process a single message you should just use JmsTemplate.

Another way to do this is to use the default message listener container, ensure threads is set to one and then make sure your activemq setup has no read-ahead setup (i.e. reads one message at a time and no more).  Then, at the end of your onMessage method, call the DMLC.stop method.